# Chain operations on a series without writing a function that does the operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```py
names | age
------+------
"John"| 20
"Doe" | 30
```

and (for the case of the example) say I want to first convert the name to upper-cases and then get the last letter. I can write my own function like

```py
def last_upper_letter(name):
  name = name.upper()
  return name[-1]
```

and use it with `apply`

```py
df["names"].apply(last_upper_letter)

#N
#E
```

Isn't there a way to call operations `.upper` and `[-1]` on each element without having to write the function as above e.g something like

```py
df["names"].apply_operations([".upper","[-1]"])

#N
#E
```

Comment: ``df.names.str.upper().str[-1]`` ?

Comment: Yeah ... that was really embarrassing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anonymous function and `apply()` method:

```
df['names'].apply(lambda x:x.upper()[-1])
```

**OR**

AS mentioned by @sammywemmy use:

```
df['names'].str.upper().str[-1]
```

**OR**

You can also do this by using `Series()` method and list comprehension:

```
pd.Series([x.upper()[-1] for x in df['names']],name='names')
```